# Find size of string on specific font

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to center a string, but that string changes size depending on a boolean. I want this string to always be centered on my screen. I'm using Graphics to draw.

So I need to do something like this :

```
String a = boolean ? "Ok" : "Nope";
graphics.drawString(a, width / 2 - a.width, 10);
```

I'm not sure how exactly to find the width of the string. I assume there is something in graphics.font, but I can't find it :(

Comment: Width of a string? Maybe you want the *length* ?

Comment: put two blank spaces in " OK "

Comment: Have a look at FontMetrics, which you can ascertain from the Graphics object

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, it had a nice method 'stringWidth'.

Comment: @khAn That's very cheaty. But that also works. I assume this would cause problems at some point however (although I can't think of a situation where it would currently). So I'll be using Mad's answer, but thank you anyway :).